# How does one find anything that isn't human or a monster in adventure mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I seem to have a problem finding non-human races that are willing to talk. I've tried finding the dwarves, and there was nothing at the place they're supposed to be. I tried finding elves... Well, I guess I found the forest retreat but there were no elves. I tried finding the GOBLINS, but where it says the dark fortress is, there is nothing. And no matter how many times I try, how many different worlds I try in, and how many different sites I try, I can't find anything. Could someone help me understand what's happening and maybe understand how to find one?

I'm using Dwarf Fortress v0.31.18, SDL.

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally, elves may populate originally human structures, such as fortresses. I once found a fort that was **rotten** with elves. Being immortal, they have populated it with at least 300 elves. The fort also housed an elf king, leading me to believe the elves had been assimilated into a human civilization, then the humans died out, leading to a civilization of city elves.